# Deneb Card containing Text + Bar Chart (Vega-Lite)

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I'm trying to create a card using Deneb, the card should contain a Measure representing total revenue added as Text, and below it a bar chart that breaks the revenue by month.

I have created the bar chart with no problem, but when I add the Text Mark and add the measure to it, it is added to the chart as data points (which is not what I want)

This is my code:

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Year Month short",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": null
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Revenue",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": null
        },
        "color": {"value": "gray"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the result

[image]

Desired result

[image]

A sample Power BI file can be found below:
[PBIX Sample file](https://cloud.degoo.com/share/OFPTR5znFMEcezYqdXK_RQ)
Your help is so much appreciated.

Best regards,
Simon

Comment: Please supply some sample data. Please also mark your old questions as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was very simple actually

```
"encoding": {
    "text": {
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "field": "Revenue",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "format": "#,##,,.00M;(#,##,,.00M)",
      "formatType": "pbiFormat"
    }
  }
```

It was this part of the code that aggregated the data points:

```
"aggregate": "sum"
```